# If $D$ is not rectifiable, then I think we cannot say $\int_D f$ exists in general. Is this an error? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.)

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

In this book, a set is defined ***rectifiable*** if and only if the set is Jordan-measurable.

> Theorem 16.5. Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition of unity on $A$ having compact supports. The integral $\int_A f$ exists if and only if the series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\int_A \phi_i |f|]$$ converges; in this case, $$\int_A f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\int_A \phi_if].$$ Note that the integral $\int_A\phi_i f$ exists and equals the ordinary integral $\int_{S_i}\phi_i f$ (where $S_i=\text{Support }\phi_i$) by the preceding lemma.

> Proof.
> $\cdots$
> Step 2. Suppose $f$ is non-negative on $A$, and suppose $f$ is integrable over $A$. We show the series $\sum [\int_A \phi_i f]$ converges, and $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\int_A \phi_i f]\leq\int_A f.$$ Given $N$, the set $D=S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_N$ is compact. Futhermore, for $i=1,\dots, N$, the function $\phi_i f$ vanishes outside $D$, so that $$\int_A \phi_i f=\int_D \phi_i f$$ by the preceding lemma. We conclude that $$\sum_{i=1}^N [\int_A \phi_i f]=\sum_{i=1}^N [\int_D \phi_i f]\\=\int_D [\sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i f] \,\,\,\,\,\text{  by linearity,}\\\leq \int_D f\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{by the comparison property,}$$

If $D$ is not rectifiable, then I think we cannot say $\int_D f$ exists in general.
Is this an error?

---

Can we change

> Let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition of unity on $A$ having compact supports.

to

> Let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition of unity on $A$ having compact rectifiable supports.

?

In fact the author constructed a partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}$ such that each $\text{Support }\phi_i$ is a closed rectangle in Theorem 16.3. And closed rectangles are rectifiable.
But the author didn't say each $\text{Support }\phi_i$ is rectifiable in the statement of Theorem 16.3.

If we change

> Let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition of unity on $A$ having compact supports.

to

> Let $\{\phi_i\}$ be a partition of unity on $A$ having compact rectifiable supports.

then, is it possible to happen any trouble when we want to use Theorem 16.5?

Is there a situation in which we want to use a partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}$ on $A$ which has compact supports which are not rectifiable?

Comment: D is a union of the sets $S_i$ and would not be a curve in general, so what would it mean for it to be rectifiable?

Comment: @coffeemath thank you very much for your comment. In this book, the author says a set is rectifiable if and only if the set is Jordan-measurable.

Comment: With that definition yes there is something to prove; perhaps another user can clear it up.

Comment: @coffeemath thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Indeed Munkres defines $S$ to be rectifiable if $\int_S1$ exists. Equivalently $S$ is rectifiable iff $S$ is bounded and $\partial S$ has measure zero. This is worth stating since rectifiable is probably more commonly used for curves, as another user mentioned (Munkres also even acknowledges his atypical usage in the text).

Comment: @pancini thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was too worried, but all that was needed was the simple modification below.

I was reading https://archive.org/details/MunkresJ.R.AnalysisOnManifoldsTotal/page/n153/mode/2up.

But in my printed book, the following

> $$\sum_{i=1}^N [\int_A \phi_i f]=\sum_{i=1}^N [\int_D \phi_i f]\\=\int_D [\sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i f] \,\,\,\,\,\text{  by linearity,}\\\leq \int_D f\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{by the comparison property,}$$

is modified as follows:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^N [\int_A \phi_i f]=\int_A [\sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i f] \,\,\,\,\,\text{  by linearity,}\\\leq \int_A f\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{by the comparison property}.$$

[image]

Comment: Nice catch. This was bothering me because it was not obvious to me at all why $\int_D f$ exists. I still can't tell if it does exist or if the original print had a genuine error.

Comment: @pancini thank you very much for your comment.